# OData with $expand doesn't work

Tags: odata, sapui5

I try to use $expand parameter in view xml but combobox doesn't display data

[image]

```
        <Text text="ID_PLANNING"/>
        <ComboBox items="{path :'/T027_03s', parameters:{expand : 'T027Details'}}">
            <core:Item text="{T027Details/BEG_DATETIME}"/>
        </ComboBox>
```

When $expand T027Details from T027_03s table, the link ..../T027_03s?$expand=T027Details

[image]

Here is $metadata for T027_03 table with navigation property: T027Details

[image]

Here is my code of creation entity in Java

> @Entity
>       public class T027_03 implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_T027_03")  
private Long ID_PERSONNEL_PLANNING;
private Integer ID_PERSONNEL;
private Long ID_PLANNING;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
[...]
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID_PLANNING")
private T027 T027;

public T027 getT027() {
    return this.T027;
}
public void setT027(T027 T027) {
    this.T027 = T027;
}
[...]
}
```

And in classe T027

> @Entity
>       public class T027 implements Serializable {

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_T027")
private Long ID_PLANNING;
private Timestamp BEG_DATETIME;
[...]
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="T027")
private List<T027_03> T027_03S;

public List<T027_03> getT027_03S() {
    return this.T027_03S;
}
public void setT027_03S(List<T027_03> T027_03S) {
    this.T027_03S = T027_03S;
}
```

I have seen the same question [OData Model Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495687/odata-model-not-working) but I don't know how to resolve it. Their reponse is to add "RESULT".. . but how I can add 'RESULT' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution has been sovled for now. I've added ***@Cache(isolation=CacheIsolationType.ISOLATED)*** to T027 table

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Cache;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.CacheIsolationType;

@Id 
@Cache(isolation=CacheIsolationType.ISOLATED)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_T027")
private Long ID_PLANNING;
private Timestamp BEG_DATETIME;
[...]
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="T027",cascade =CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<T027_03> T027_03S;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997508/why-is-expand-not-working-correct-in-my-jpa-olingo-project) is the solution I found

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding parent entity name in combo box item key and text

```
<core:Item key="{T027_03s/T027Details/ID_PLANNING}" text="{T027_03s/T027Details/ID_PLANNING}"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. There is still no data in the combobox

Answer (score 1):

You should bind a node with multiplicity more than 1 in your "items" aggregation. The expand just retrieve more data in your request. But there is still 1 item only.

To fix it, do elementBinding of your node "T027_03s" and then aggregationBinding with your "T027Details" like the following:

```
<ComboBox binding="{path:'/T027_03s', parameters:'expand:T027Details'}" items="{T027Details}">
    <core:Item text="{ID_PLANNING}" key="{ID_PLANNING}"></core:Item>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I tried it and now there is just one empty line when I drop down the combobox instead of 2 records from data base. (ie my preview sample )

Comment: Wait a sec. Maybe I didn't understand you well... Where do you have the collection of items you want to iterate?? In '/T027_03s' ?? Or in 'T027Details'??

Comment: In the T027_03 table, I have 'navigation property' 'T027Details' .<NavigationProperty Name="T027Details" Relationship="AtosForm.T027_03_T027_Many_One0" FromRole="T027_03" ToRole="T027"/>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to access a property (`ID_PLANNING`) of the `T027_03s` entity type.

If you bind your `ComboBox` items to look like:

```
<ComboBox items="{path :'/T027_03s', parameters:{expand : 'T027Details'}}">
    <core:Item key="{ID_PLANNING}" text="{ID_PLANNING}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

You should see results from the `T027_03s` entity set

But...
If you are looking to display a property on `T027Details`, your binding syntax looks like it should work so long as you are binding a valid property of the `T027Details` entity type.

In other words, if you wanted to display a valid property `DETAIL_PROPERTY` that is part of the `T027Details` entity set for each entry in T027_03s, you would do it like:

```
<ComboBox items="{path :'/T027_03s', parameters:{expand : 'T027Details'}}">
    <core:Item key="{T027Details/DETAIL_PROPERTY}" text="{T027Details/DETAIL_PROPERTY}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I have modifed code of combobox : <core:Item text="{T027Details/BEG_DATETIME}"/> with BEG_DATETIME is a property of T027Details (beacause my old exemple was not claire). The result is still empty.                         P/S: It will display value when I restart Java application... Did you see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495687/odata-model-not-working ? I don't know how they resolved

Comment: Ok, with your last edit, the problem is not on the frontend, assuming `BEG_DATETIME` is a valid property of the `T027Details` association. On inspecting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erD7N.png) screenshot more closely, you do not have any data coming through in the OData call from T027Details. If the call had gone correctly, you would see a T027Details entity nested in the `<inline></inline>` tag. Check with your backend service about getting data to the frontend properly via your association.

Comment: I updated my question to give you more information about the creation entities (tables) in java. Can you give me some advices about options "@ManytoOne" and "@OnetoMany"  that I use in the association?